# Electron Create React App not loading after build

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, build, electron

I've created a test react project with the `npx create react app` and added the electron.js file. I then run the build script and it was compiled successfully but when I try to run the .exe nothing shows and the console returns a `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`.

electron.js

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require("electron");
const path = require("path");
const isDev = require("electron-is-dev");

function createWindow() {
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1920,
    height: 1080,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js"),
    },
  });

  mainWindow.loadURL(
    isDev
      ? "http://localhost:3000"
      : `file://${path.join(__dirname, "../build/index.html")}`
  );

  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
}

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow();

  app.on("activate", function () {
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow();
  });
});

app.on("window-all-closed", function () {
  if (process.platform !== "darwin") app.quit();
});
```

EDIT: so I tried again from the start and managed to build with just the create-react-app however I've now changed some files with a Routes component and while in dev works fine when I build it nothing shows. console.log are shown but the component isn't.

routes.js

```
const routes = [
  {
    exact: true,
    path: "/",
    component: lazy(() => import("../test")),
  },
];

const renderRoutes = (routes) =>
  routes ? (
    <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
      <Switch>
        {routes.map((route, i) => {
          const Layout = route.layout || Fragment;
          const Component = route.component;

          console.log({ Component });

          return (
            <Route
              key={i}
              path={route.path}
              exact
              render={(props) => (
                <Layout>
                  {route.routes ? (
                    renderRoutes(route.routes)
                  ) : (
                    <Component {...props} />
                  )}
                </Layout>
              )}
            />
          );
        })}
      </Switch>
    </Suspense>
  ) : null;

const Routes = () => {
  return renderRoutes(routes);
};

export default Routes;
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using `react-router-dom` library to handle the route in *electron* & *React* App, and removing that (routing using `react-router-dom`) worked for me.

**Old Code:**

This code worked fine in a development environment but when I generated a build using `electron-builder`, It was showing an empty page/screen.

```
import { createContext, useState } from "react";
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import Data from "./screens/Data";

const GlobalContext = createContext();

export default function App() {
    let [user, setUser] = useState("");
    return (
        <main className="h-[100vh]" data-theme="light">
            <GlobalContext.Provider value={{ user, setUser }}>
                <Routes>
                    <Route path="/" element={<Data />} />
                </Routes>
            </GlobalContext.Provider>
        </main>
    );
}

export { GlobalContext };
```

**Modified Code:**

```
import { createContext, useState } from "react";

import Data from "./screens/Data";

const GlobalContext = createContext();

export default function App() {
    let [user, setUser] = useState("Vrial");
    return (
        <main className="h-[100vh]" data-theme="light">
            <GlobalContext.Provider value={{ user, setUser }}>
                <Data />
            </GlobalContext.Provider>
        </main>
    );
}

export { GlobalContext };
```

**Possible Reason:**

- URLs like `/`, `/home`, `/any` might not be recognized by the production app (.exe).

Answer (score -1):

Problem might be in the fact, that you have changed name for one of the main files, for example electron searches for special filename when building. Please check your filenames.

This error means that file was not found. Either path is wrong or file is not present where you want it to be.

Comment: But I didn't change any file names. I did the npx create react app then add the electron.js file to the public folder and updated the package.json

Comment: That behavior and exception only come up when you either messed up filenames or when installation is corrupt or missing elements. However there is one more cause to that - when you have different CPU architecture, ie ARM based CPU. Please check where exactly your electron is searching for missing module and please provide expanded console output. You can change pathnames (in case of privacy), of course.